# CLNDR.js pass variable into underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have created a calendar with CLNDR.js. Everything works very well but I want to pass the selected date into Underscore to show only the events day.

Part of my clndr html:

```
<div class="events-list">
    <% _.each(eventsThisMonth, function(event) { %>

        <!--<% if (event.date == selectedDate) { %>-->

            <div class="event">
                <a href="<%= event.url %>">. <%= event.location %></a>
            </div>

        <!--<% } %>-->

    <% }); %>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(window).load(function(){

$('#mini-clndr').clndr({
    template: $('#calendar').html(),
    events: events,

    clickEvents: {
        click: function(target) {
            if(target.events.length) {

                var selectedDate = target.date['_i'];

                var controls = $('#mini-clndr').find('.controls');                          
                var daysContainer = $('#mini-clndr').find('.days-container');
                var eventsContainer = $('#mini-clndr').find('.events');

                controls.slideUp( "slow" );
                daysContainer.slideUp( "slow" );
                eventsContainer.slideDown( "slow" );

                $('#mini-clndr').find('.x-button').click( function() {
                    controls.slideDown( "slow" );
                    daysContainer.slideDown( "slow" );
                    eventsContainer.slideUp( "slow" );
                });

            }

        }
    },

    adjacentDaysChangeMonth: false

  });
});
```

Someone can help me? It's the first time I use Underscore.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your issue is not related to underscore.js

You cannot use selectedDate in the clndr template. This template is used only when you render the calendar (so at the beginning or at a call to render), not on a click event.

Then it's difficult to give you a correct code without the full clndr template. But maybe something like that could work :

```
<% _.each(eventsThisMonth, function(event) { %>
    <div class="event-item <%= event.date %>">
        <div class="event-item-name"><%= event.title %></div>
        <div class="event-item-location"><%= event.location %></div>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```

and in your js :

```
(...)
$(".events-list ." + selectedDate).show();
controls.slideUp( "slow" );
(...)
$('#mini-clndr').find('.x-button').click( function() {
    $(".events-list ." + selectedDate).hide();
(...)
```

Comment: Thank you Pierre :) I have modify a little bit your code, but it's work very well with your strategy:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible strategy:

1. Let 'event' be the event for the date the user just selected.
2. Assume this event has a corresponding element in the `eventsThisMonth` array.
3. Find its index in that array by comparing each element's date with the selected date.
4. Now use Underscore or jQuery to hide every entry in `eventsContainer` except the one for that index.

And a possible implementation (not tested):

```
$(window).load(function(){

// Get a  reference to the calendar instance
var clndrCalendar = $('#mini-clndr').clndr({
        template: $('#calendar').html(),
        events: events,

        clickEvents: {
            click: function(target) {
                if(target.events.length) {

                    var selectedDate = target.date;  // 'Moment' object from moment.js
                    var eventsThisMonth = clndrCalendar.eventsThisMonth;
                    var found = false;               // boolean - Do we have a match
                    for(var index = 0; index < eventsThisMonth.length; index++) {
                        // Compares the two dates using moment.js 'sameAs' method - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/
                        if(selectedDate.sameAs(eventsThisMonth[index].date)) {
                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(found) {
                        var jqEvents = $('#mini-clndr .events .event');
                        var jqSelectedEvent = jqEvents.get(index);
                        if(jqSelectedEvent) {
                            jqEvents.hide();
                            jqSelectedEvent.show();
                        }
                    }

                    var controls = $('#mini-clndr').find('.controls');                          
                    var daysContainer = $('#mini-clndr').find('.days-container');
                    var eventsContainer = $('#mini-clndr').find('.events');

                    controls.slideUp( "slow" );
                    daysContainer.slideUp( "slow" );
                    eventsContainer.slideDown( "slow" );

                    $('#mini-clndr').find('.x-button').click( function() {
                        controls.slideDown( "slow" );
                        daysContainer.slideDown( "slow" );
                        eventsContainer.slideUp( "slow" );
                    });
                }
            }
        },

        adjacentDaysChangeMonth: false

    });
});
```

Comment: I try your strategy too... "clndrCalendar" what does that represent? The script id?

Comment: @FrancisB.Bélisle It's just a variable to hold an object reference needed by a statement a few lines below: `var eventsThisMonth = clndrCalendar.eventsThisMonth;`. You can freely rename it as long as you rename both its occurences..